# Wrapping adjacent divs around a float element

Tags: html, css

I want to have 2 columns of text, or other elements, that have 50/50 width and wrap around an element that has `float` property set.

What is happening is that when I use flex, grid or inline-block, my 2 columns completely avoid the float element, i.e. just go below the float element.

```css
#container {
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  /* display: flex; */
}

#left {
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
}

#right {
  width: 40%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

:root {
  --page-width: 700px;
  --page-height: 100px;
  --top-margin: 10px;
  --left-margin: 10px;
  --bottom-margin: 10px;
  --right-margin: 10px;
}

.soup-image {
  display: block;
  width: calc(var(--page-width) - var(--left-margin) - var(--right-margin));
  height: calc(var(--page-height) + 20px);
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 100%;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% var(--top-margin), 0 var(--top-margin), 0 calc(100% - 1 * var(--bottom-margin) - 20px), 100% calc(100% - 1 * var(--bottom-margin) - 20px), 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(white var(--top-margin), transparent var(--top-margin), transparent calc(100% - 1 * var(--bottom-margin) - 20px), white calc(100% - 1 * var(--bottom-margin) - 20px));
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="soup-image">

</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  </div>
  <div id="right">

    Why do we use it? The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make both columns wrap around the element?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish. How exactly do you want the columns to wrap around the floated element? Be positioned side-by-side next to the floated element or below it? Can you create a graphical example?

Comment: Sounds like you need shape-outside but it's really not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. What I want is this: imagine in my example to have the #right div next to #left div, and that they both wrap around the .soup-image, like #left div already does